# Nested Promise structure order

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, typescript, promise

I'm trying to achieve something a bit tricky as I'm not used to Promise yet.

I want to fill a map of `<Id, ObjectInfo>`

I have two API points :

- one gets all users
- the other one gets the ObjectInfo given an Id

This is what I have :

```
const result: Map<string, String[]> = new Map();
return this.http.get(this.adress + '/', this.options).toPromise()
  .then((response) => {
    for (const id of response.json()){
      this.http.get(this.adress + '/' + id + '/properties').toPromise()
      .then((rep) => {
        result.set(id, rep.json());
        console.log('#1: ', result);
      }).catch(this.handleError)
    }
  })
  .then(() => console.log('#2: ', result))
  .then(() => result)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

So here, I would like the #1 to be followed by the #2 in the console, but it's not the case. I'm aware that I should try with a `Promise.all()` but I don't really know how to set it up, since I'm creating my Promises in a nested loop.

This is for an Angular project, the actual code is working so far, but throws an *ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError*.
To avoid it, changing my promise function should do the trick.

Comment: why are you promise did you tried with observables?

Comment: don't change the expression after it was checked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The angular tag should be used for the Angular framework, versions 2 and above. The angularjs tag should be used only for the AngularJS framework, versions in the 1.x range. Please [edit] your question to remove the tag for the version you're not using.

Comment: Since this isn't plain Javascript, please tag it with the language you are using.

Comment: Nested loop? I don't see that. And it doesn't matter. All you need to do is to return a promise from your `then` callback in which you are looping.

Comment: Jonnysai I'm just a developer in this project, and promises are being used rather than observables.  

RomanC Well, I wish I could, but this occurs when I'm calling the function in ngOnInit() .  
  
MikeMcCaughan jfriend00 Sure, fixed it !  

Bergi Indeed, as nem035 suggested.  

Thanks everyone for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the code

```
.then((response) => {
  // <-- HERE -->
  // this function must return a promise

  for (const id of response.json()){
    // ...
  }
})
.then(() => {
  // right now, this function executes **before** the requests
  // in the promise above are resolved
});
```

Must return a promise resolving to all the individual promises within it (the ones built in the loop) so the promise chain can have the order you want - wait for all promises in the loop before continuing.

Using `Promise.all` here is a natural fit, just replace `for..of` with array mapping:

```
.then((response) => {
  return Promise.all(
    Array
      .from(response.json())
      .map(id => {
        return this.http.get(this.adress + '/' + id + '/properties')
          .toPromise()
          .then((rep) => {
            result.set(id, rep.json());
            console.log('#1: ', result);
          })
          .catch(this.handleError)
      })
  );
})
.then(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is now as I wanted ! Still getting the *ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError* tho, I'll figure it out